# What are the Keys of the Unseen?

Tags: quran, tafseer, ilm-al-ghaib

Allah says about Himself in Surah Al-An'aam:

> وَعِندَهُ مَفَاتِحُ الْغَيْبِ لَا يَعْلَمُهَا إِلَّا هُوَ
>
> And with Him are the keys of the unseen; none knows them except Him
>
> [Al-An'aam:59](http://tanzil.net/#6:59)

What is meant by the "Keys of the Unseen"?

Answer (score 5):

### The Keys of the Unseen are five matters...

*... that are related to the knowledge of the unseen, which only Allah possesses*

---

***As mentioned in verse 34 of Surah Luqmaan:***

1. When the Hour (Day of Judgment) will be
2. When (and where) it will rain
3. What is in the mother's womb, i.e. the child's gender
4. What will happen tomorrow
5. Where a person will die

The verse reads:

> إِنَّ اللَّـهَ عِندَهُ عِلْمُ السَّاعَةِ وَيُنَزِّلُ الْغَيْثَ وَيَعْلَمُ مَا فِي الْأَرْحَامِ  وَمَا تَدْرِي نَفْسٌ مَّاذَا تَكْسِبُ غَدًا  وَمَا تَدْرِي نَفْسٌ بِأَيِّ أَرْضٍ تَمُوتُ  إِنَّ اللَّـهَ عَلِيمٌ خَبِيرٌ
>
> Verily, Allah! With Him (Alone) is the knowledge of the Hour, He sends down the rain, and knows that which is in the wombs. No person knows what he will earn tomorrow, and no person knows in what land he will die. Verily, Allah is All-Knower, All-Aware (of things).
>
> [Luqmaan:34](http://tanzil.net/#31:34)

---

***This is also reinforced in [several Ahaadeeth](https://www.sunnah.com/search/?q=keys%20unseen) recorded by Bukhari in his Saheeh***

Narrated by 'Abdullah Ibn 'Umar, that the Prophet ﷺ said:

> مَفَاتِيحُ الْغَيْبِ خَمْسٌ لاَ يَعْلَمُهَا إِلاَّ اللَّهُ،
>   لاَ يَعْلَمُ مَا تَغِيضُ الأَرْحَامُ إِلاَّ اللَّهُ،
>   وَلاَ يَعْلَمُ مَا فِي غَدٍ إِلاَّ اللَّهُ،
>   وَلاَ يَعْلَمُ مَتَى يَأْتِي الْمَطَرُ أَحَدٌ إِلاَّ اللَّهُ،
>   وَلاَ تَدْرِي نَفْسٌ بِأَىِّ أَرْضٍ تَمُوتُ إِلاَّ اللَّهُ،
>   وَلاَ يَعْلَمُ مَتَى تَقُومُ السَّاعَةُ إِلاَّ اللَّهُ
>
> The keys of the unseen are five and none knows them but Allah:
>   (1) None knows (the sex of) what is in the womb, except Allah:
>   (2) None knows what will happen tomorrow, except Allah;
>   (3) None knows when it will rain, except Allah;
>   (4) None knows where he will die, except Allah (knows that);
>   (5) and none knows when the Hour will be established, except Allah.
>
> [Bukhari, Book 97, Hadeeth 9](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/97/9)

Comment: Why did you ask a question than answer it yourself?

Comment: @Armaan https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer . In a nutshell, Stack Exchange encourages the sharing of information in this format

Comment: Did you just ask it because you wanted reputation as you asked the question and answered it 14 minutes ago?

Comment: The rep score is a by-product of the process of posting up the Q&A. The real benefit is in contributing information to the site that was not present before. This isn't the first time I've done this on SE: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/40073530/133939 , https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/15387/675, https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/23767/675 ...

Comment: That is weird...

Comment: Is there no precedent for a self-answered Q&A on the site?

Comment: I think sometimes it is good to "ask" questions and answer them oneself, then it is also possible to refer back to these questions in other answers, which helps one to keep the answer well detailed and structured. It should not be discouraged. And by the way, other always has the possibility to answer with a more detailed answer or with another point of view.